# How can I assign a bitmap to a Image control in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, bitmap

I have an asp.net file as follows:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to set the Image1 in the c# using the following code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap oBmp1 = new Bitmap(460, 60);
    Graphics oGrp1 = Graphics.FromImage(oBmp1);
    Color ocolor = new Color();
    ocolor = Color.Yellow;
    SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(ocolor);
    SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    oGrp1.FillRectangle(oBrush, 100, 25, 500, 75);
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    oBmp1.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

How can I directly set the image1 in c# after I generate the bitmap without saving bitmap as an image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above solution won't work.

You have to create a separate handler (.ashx) to return image. You will have to pass appropriate parameters as query string and link it to your Image control

See this https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111734/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042209-1.aspx

Comment: How can I create a separate handler?

Comment: see modified answer

Answer (score 0):

you can save the bitmap as image file in any folder and use your image control to locate your image file path to display the image.

Comment: How can I directly set the image1 in c# after I generate the bitmap without saving bitmap as an image file?